# can not Return json result when form is not valid

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have an action that it send form to action with Ajax like below :

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm(MVC.Admin.DeviceGroup.Create(), new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", OnSuccess = "saveAjaxForm", OnFailure = "SaveFailure" }))
{...}
```

action  is :

```
        public virtual JsonResult Create(AddDeviceGroupViewModel deviceGroupViewModel)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsNotValid())
        {
            Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
            return Json(new { success = false, message = ModelState.FirstErrorMessage(), notificationType = NotificationType.Error }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }}
```

and my `js` function is :

```
function SaveFailure(data) {

console.log('saveFailure');

$("button[type=submit]").prop('disabled', false);
var result = $.parseJSON(data.responseText);
showMessage(result.message, result.notificationType);
}
```

but when I inspect in `network` tab I have just this result :
[image]

I've got this error message :

> SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

`IsNotValid` is an ExtensionMethod:

```
        public static bool IsNotValid(this ModelStateDictionary modelState)
    {
        return !modelState.IsValid;
    }
```

and `FirstErrorMessage` is :

```
public static string FirstErrorMessage(this ModelStateDictionary modelState)
    {
        return modelState.Select(row => row.Value.Errors).Where(row => row.Count > 0).FirstOrDefault().First().ErrorMessage;
    }
```

Comment: @StephenMuecke it didn't return anything . in response I just have BadRequest .

Comment: Your method is returning a Bad Request, so of course you will get that. Add `console.log(result.message);` and `console.log(result.notificationType);` after `var result = $.parseJSON(data.responseText);` - what is the output? (works fine for me when I hard code some values)

Comment: @StephenMuecke I've got this ` JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data` . I think there is not `parseJSON` method /

Comment: Yes there is. Just comment out the `return` code and replace with `return Json(new { message = "abc", notificationType = "zyz" });` for testing

Comment: no its return same error . when I change like this :`console.log(JSON.stringify(data));` I got this result:  `{"readyState":4,"responseText":"Bad Request","status":400,"statusText":"Bad Request"}`

Comment: Not for me - its `{"readyState":4,"responseText":"{\"message\":\"abc\",\"notificationType\":\"zyz\"}","responseJSON":{"message":"abc","notificationType":"zyz"},"status":400,"statusText":"Bad Request"}`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136604/discussion-between-work-question-and-stephen-muecke).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After an hour , I found the problem . I had this in my `web.config`

```
 <httpErrors errorMode="Custom">
  <remove statusCode="404"/>
  <error statusCode="404" path="/Error/NotFound" responseMode="ExecuteURL"/>
</httpErrors>
```

I commented it and it work fine.

**another ways :**
use this code :

```
Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;
```

or change `errorMode` to `DetailedLocalOnly` Like :

```
 <httpErrors errorMode="DetailedLocalOnly">
  <remove statusCode="404"/>
  <error statusCode="404" path="/Error/NotFound" responseMode="ExecuteURL"/>
</httpErrors>
```